# How to batch-rename the labels of existing labview controls?

Tags: rename, labview

Let's say I have a front panel with 100 buttons named "Button 1"..."Button 100". How can I quickly rename all of them to "Push Button 1"..."Push Button 100"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same answer as Dave_St but as vi snippet.

[image: VI Snippet]

Before running the VI:

[image]

And After running the VI:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done programmatically but the vi whose control names are to be changed must not be running in any way (it can be loaded into memory but the run button must be flat white).

Get all the front panel references from the vi. Then change their names with another vi using the Label.Text property.

Answer (score 0):

That is a really good question, if you can't just get rid of them and make a new button called "Push Button 1" that you use to create all the others. I'm assuming they're already implemented enough to make that difficult. I can't test it out on the machine I'm at, but I'd create a new VI and open a reference to the VI with your buttons in it. Then you can get the references to all the front panel controls, which you can then run through a loop that checks if it's a button and then changes the label.